# SPI consumes more power than I2C?

Tags: sensor, i2c, spi, current-measurement

Does anyone know if SPI typically draws more current than I2C? The reason I'm asking is that I'm playing with the [LIS3DH](https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/LIS3DH.pdf) accelerometer and driving it with an Arduino. When I2C is used, the current draw is about 30uA (300uV across a 10R shunt). This is achieved with SDO connected to VDD rather than GND. However, when SPI is used, the current draw is about 300uA (3mV across a 10R shunt).

Because I2C doesn't use SDO, it could be connected to VDD to reduce current draw. The same cannot be done when SPI is used since SDO is used - correct? I wonder if SDO somehow drains current.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

First I want to consider I2C vs SPI in general terms.

I2C requires pull-up resistors to create the 3.3V or 5V idle state. When any device (either clock or data) pulls that line low, it will effectively put the pull-up resistor between VCC and GND. Depending on the value of pull-up you will see a much larger current draw than uA's.

E.g. 3.3V bus with 3.3k pull-ups is a 1mA current draw.

However it's not that simple: the clock won't be low for 100% of the time. Maybe 10% on a reasonably busy bus. In that case the RMS current is amplitude * sqrt(duty) [RMS formula for a pulse train] -> 1mA * sqrt(0.1) = 0.316mA.
Also take into consideration there are 2 I2C lines.
And worst of all; if you may be using a "lazy I2C software implementation"; watch out for bus collisions. E.g. a I2C slave that wants to use clock stretching, while the I2C master uses push-pull GPIO's to drive the bus.

SPI is much simpler because often there are no pull-ups. The only power consumption it has is dynamic consumption from switching transistors and I/O lines.

If you do use SPI with pull-ups you will also see a (slight) increase in power consumption. However also note that a SPI has different SPI modes, and may idle at a logic low level. In that case the pull-up will continuously consume extra current.

In your case, as we don't have a schematic on exactly which SDO pin you're pulling low, you are maybe pulling the I2C SDA pin low with the pull-ups still in place?

Comment: I'm actually using SPI with the I2C pull-up still in place. Does using pull-ups along with SPI cause a larger current draw?

Comment: I've added a paragraph about SPI and pull-ups. Yes initially I described how pull-ups cause slightly more current draw. In I2C pull-ups are inherent to how the bus is made, and in SPI it's optional.
However note that on e.g. SPI mode 0,0 all digital I/O may idle at a logic low, consuming extra current continuously.